# Why is vdirsyncer choking?

Tags: shell-script, python

I had `vdirsyncer` running just fine for eons, on a computer that I don't use every day (or even every week). And then about a month ago I tried to run `vdirsyncer sync` and it choked with:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f9038c2b740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't remember screwing around in my python settings so I don't know why it would have just stopped working. I suspect that someone who spends more time in Python than I do these days might know what happened?

I'd like to fix this without trashing python, which currently defaults to 2.7 unless I specify that I want `python3`.

I found a question that cites the same error text, but the answer there recommends unsetting `$PYTHONHOME` and I haven't set it:

[Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding … SyntaxError: invalid syntax Aborted (core dumped)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640010/fatal-python-error-py-initialize-unable-to-get-the-locale-encoding-syntaxe)

Answers to questions in the comments:

- I'm on Ubuntu 18.04
- I don't remember how I initially installed but I reinstalled with `apt` which didn't solve anything.

Comment: Which distro? What version of vdirsyncer? How are you installing? FWIW I think the latest version is for python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled with `pip3 install --user --ignore-installed vdirsyncer` which seems to have gotten it working again. Still not sure how I broke it.